# After converting PDF to PPTX in Google Drive file is corrupted and can only view first slide

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

It seems I'm having an issue converting a PDF to a pptx in Google drive. Originally I wanted to convert a PDF to a google slide but, it will only go from pdf -> google doc.

Since I've had luck going from pptx -> google slide. I thought I would have better luck going that route. The issue is after converting from PDF to pptx it seems that the file is corrupted. I can view the first slide but I am not able to open it as a Google slide.

This is what I have for getting the pdf as a pptx

```
Drive.Files.insert({title: 'test.pptx', mimeType: MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT, parents: [{id: ID}]}, powerPoint.getBlob())
```

Comment: What make you think that Google Drive API is able to convert a PDF to PPTX? What app was used to create the PDF?

Comment: @Rubén I exported it out of adobe indesign. I assumed you could because you can go from pdf -> doc. My end goal is to be able to upload pdfs then run a script to normalize them within google slides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert PDF and image files to text with Google Drive as is described [Convert PDF and photo files to text](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/176692?hl=en) but AFAIK there isn't any official doc that mentions the conversion of PDF to Google Slides.

Instead of using the Google Drive services you should use a library or another service that offer that kind of conversion.